# Preventing browser cache issues in ASP.NET, and testing

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, caching

Some users who are using IE8 are getting cached content, I added the below snippet to my global.asax.cs to force their browsers to get new content:

```
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
  Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
  Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
```

Assuming the average user who doesn't know anything about modifying the cache settings in IE, how can I test if my changes will work?

I'm not really sure why they would be experiencing caching issues (getting stale content) when I am running the same browser on my computer? (being the naive programmer I am hehe)

**Also, I want to make sure I am not wiping out their cookies or preventing their cookies from being stored etc.**

Comment: Very recent blog post on this: http://madskristensen.net/post/Cache-busting-in-ASPNET.aspx

Comment: @Oded Thanks, really good blog post indeed

Comment: This link has changed since then - http://madskristensen.net/post/cache-busting-in-aspnet - looks like he just removed the .aspx

Answer (score 0):

The safest, most reliable way to force the re-download of a file (prevent caching) is to append a unique identifier, timestamp, or version number to the URL.

In fact, for my projects, I generally instruct clients to cache *most* resources (with exception for certain async/data requests and/or content with sensitive information) unless "instructed" to re-download, which is done by incrementing version numbers.